# Importing data using SQL Server Import Wizard results in weird characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2016 Import and Export Wizard

Source IS Flat file (`.txt`):

[image]

[image]

Please note the data in column 3: it should read ***Île-de-France***

Comment: how are the columns defined ? are they varchar in stead of nvarchar ? And is the text file a unicode file ?

Comment: no idea: where am I supposed to see or change column datatype definition?

Comment: I never used the import wizard so I dont know either. But your problem seems unicode related. Is the text file a unicode file ? You can check that when opening in notepad. If so than adapt your settings in the wizard also to unicode

Comment: I can open the file with notepad+ and characters are correctly visualized. I supposed the encoding may be Unicode but when I check Unicode on Wizard's firs page I receive a pop-up error about the data row delimiter and no columns are shown.

Comment: You are not using notepad++ to do the import so how it shows the contents does not matters. Can you check using notepad++ or regular notepad if the file is a unicode file or not

Comment: Check encoding in notepad++ main menu, and tell us what you see there

Comment: Notepad++ Encoding shows UTF-8 checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct procedure for importing tab-delimited text in utf8 encoding.

In the firs page of the Wizard, instead of checking "Unicode" (that's quite confusing because UTF-8 'is' Unicode) leave it unchecked and select Code page 65001

[image]

Now characters are being correctly visualized:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is Unicode Error that's y words is not showing properly. Go to the advance tab and select your third column as shown in fig:
[image]

Choose data type string to "text stream [DT_TEXT]", If "text stream [DT_TEXT]" will not work then please try with other data type also. Ref this Fig :

[image]

Comment: There are 4 text datatype to choose from: string (DT_STR), text stream (DT_TEXT), Unicode string (DT_WSTR) and Unicode text stream (DT_NTEXT). Unfortunately none of them fix the problem.

Source file data format is tab-delimited text in utf8 encoding.

Comment: Can you please check again your input text file ..may be problem in your text file.

Comment: This is just an example of many other files from geonames.org. They all show same "problem" with MS SQL Server Import Wizard.  They are all tab-delimited text in utf8 encoding and I can correctly read them it any flat file reader (Notepad++ for instance), The problem seems to be in MS SQL server import Wizard not been able to correctly interpret them. Now, I understand MS SQL server may not be the best importing tool out there, but it's free. Can anyone suggest me a free alternative?

Comment: You can download this source file at http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/FR.zip and try yourself.